# Facebook Photo Zoom: How was it done?

Tags: javascript, facebook, photo, photo-gallery

[Facebook photo zoom](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/elioihkkcdgakfbahdoddophfngopipi) is one of the best utilities I have ever encountered when browsing a massive amount of photos. My question is how it was built, and if there is a free javascript application already written that mimics its functionality.

My initial search turned up a number of links on how it was a useful extension, but nothing detailing the underlying javascript. A similar programme can be found in [FFixer](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/8861).

Comment: Why not contact the person who wrote it and ask them? (http://www.regisgaughan.com/contact.html)

Comment: I'd be very interested in the JS to do something similar.  Have you tried just looking at the source in Chrome console?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the FB image URLs they are rather predictable. The mini-ones end in _q, then it gets larger with _n, etc etc...

You can make the effect however you wish, but essentially he just detects that the page is FB then on hover of an image with a certain class the image will get larger and replace _q at the end of the image with _n or whatever...

After that you can use a variety of techniques to present the image.